# The RTL css file is not working for a menu

Tags: routes, theming

I wanted to make the [CorporateClean](https://www.drupal.org/project/corporateclean) theme RTL. Every thing is Ok except Main Menu. It effects alignment for both languages. For Persian is also right and for English as well.
As example: I wrote the following code in RTL Css file

```
#header-menu ul.menu li {
float:right;
dir:rtl;
text-align:right;
}
```

It makes the menu RTL for both English  and Persian languages.

Answer (score 0):

you mistake is here     **dir:rtl;** :(, and correct code will be below "dadash"

```
#header-menu ul.menu li {
float:right;
direction:rtl;
text-align:right;
}
```

Comment: Actually I use this code direction:rtl; and exactly the code you wrote above.But the problem is that my site reads the style-rtl.css before style.css.

Comment: @jkahmadi so it can happened because of very reasons !!!, if you sure that style.css load after style-rtl.css  exchange them :D , Check the `.info` file and be sure `stylesheets[all][] = css/style-rtl.css` is after `stylesheets[all][] = css/style.css`